# Trying to limit a dynamically generated list of rows within an accordion to show in a card of fixed height with scroll

Tags: scroll, bootstrap-4, height, bootstrap-accordion

So I have built the script below to take an array, group them by one of the fields, which then generates the accordion headings.  The data within the array is then build as rows within the accordion.

What I would like to do is have the containing card be of fixed height, so that which ever accordion is clicked, then has the data scroll within the area of the card....

Bootstrap is standard for the card class.

```
        <div class="card" style="height: 80%; width: 100%">
            <div class="card-header">Service History for <?php echo $vesseldata['vesselTag']; echo $own;?></div>
                <div id="accordion">
                    <?php $newArray=array();
                            foreach($history as $val){
                                $key=$val['component'];
                                $grouped[$key][]=$val;
                            }
                            foreach($grouped as $group){?>
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$group[0]['component']);?>">
                                            <?php echo $group[0]['component']; ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$group[0]['component']); ?>" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card w-100">
                                            <?php foreach ($group as $occurance){?>
                                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 d-flex">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control text-primary" disabled value="<?php echo $occurance['date'];?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div  class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled value="<?php echo $occurance['engineer'];?>">                                                    
                                                </div> 
                                                <div  class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" disabled ><?php echo $occurance['comment'];?></textarea>                                                    
                                                </div> 
                                                <div  class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                     <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" disabled ><?php echo $occurance['parts'];?></textarea>                                                    
                                               </div> 
                                                <div  class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                    <a href="#mapModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-lat="<?php echo $occurance['lat'];?>" data-lng="<?php echo $occurance['longitude'];?>"><img src="small-globe.jpg" alt="Map" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:0;"></a>
                                               </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    <?php }?>
                </div>
```

Hope someone is able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your card has its height set to 80%. You are using [relative units](https://thecssworkshop.com/lessons/relative-units) which means the card will be 80% of it's **parent's height**. You have it fixed to be 80% of its parent and I'm not sure if that's what you want.

However, to enable scrolling within your card when content is too big to fit inside the card, add this property within your style attribute:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: jeez...  that simple...  Added that to the top-most ```card``` and its working.  Now to try and make it a little easier to use on a mobile device, because the ```div``` elements generated are not 'draggable' and so the only way to scroll the ```card``` is to hold some of the white space around the globe image.

Comment: No problem! If the answer was helpful to you, consider upvoting it as well. I'm not too sure on what you mean about white space around the globe. IMO, I recommend storing your styles in an external css file (it's easier to manage) and using [device mode in chrome dev tools](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-simulate-mobile-devices-with-device-mode-in-chrome/) to mock a mobile device. It should be able to scroll just by swiping.

Comment: It was because I had used the 'disable' mode on the elements, which i guess technically makes them 'un-clickable' therefore the drag/swipe, was only working on the white space around the globe img......  Sorted now as I have moved over to a table format that looks ok and works....  Up voted too ;-)